# How to obtain a stock prices with frequency 10 minutes or 30 minutes

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm attempting to export stock price data from the R program using the "quantmod" package. It provides me with data at a daily frequency, but I need to change it to a frequency of 10 minutes or 30 minutes. Unfortunately, I have not been successful in doing so. i tried the following code

```
`library(quantmod)

# symbol
symbol <- "GC=F"

#  time range (last 100 days)
start_date <- Sys.Date() - 100
end_date <- Sys.Date()

getSymbols(symbol, from = start_date, to = end_date, interval = "10 mins")

gold_data <- Cl(get(symbol))
plot(gold_data)`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a new-ish version (from GitHub) but this should be on CRAN "soon" too.

```
> GC <- getSymbols("GC=F", periodicity="30 minutes", auto.assign=FALSE)
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  Only a maximum of 7 days is allowed for querying intraday datadata from 'yahoo'. Setting `from` to '2023-08-14'.
2: GC=F contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 
> head(GC)
                    GC=F.Open GC=F.High GC=F.Low GC=F.Close GC=F.Volume
2023-08-13 20:00:00    1945.6    1945.7   1943.0     1943.4        1270
2023-08-13 20:30:00    1943.3    1943.7   1942.5     1943.0        1254
2023-08-13 21:00:00    1943.0    1944.4   1942.2     1943.0        2751
2023-08-13 21:30:00    1943.0    1945.0   1942.2     1943.5        1545
2023-08-13 22:00:00    1943.4    1943.9   1942.2     1943.3         823
2023-08-13 22:30:00    1943.2    1944.6   1943.0     1943.8         649
Warning message:
object timezone (America/New_York) is different from system timezone (America/Chicago)
  NOTE: set 'options(xts_check_TZ = FALSE)'to disable this warning
    This note is displayed once per session 
>
```

As you see in the message, only up to 7 days can be retrieved for intra-day data.  On the other hand it allows minute data so you can grow some intra-day archives on a rolling-forward basis if you archive the snapshots locally.

Comment: I'm working on the release that will include this now. It should be on CRAN today, with Windows binaries built in the next day or two.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for tossing the `auto.assign` in which I have covered here via `.Rprofile`.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why it gives me an error? maybe the reason is what you said that it is not yet on cran? it gives me : Error in match.arg(periodicity, names(intervals)) : 
  'arg' should be one of “daily”, “weekly”, “monthly”

Comment: Correct. Until the functionality you want is in the version at CRAN, you need to `remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")`.  The restart your R session, load `quantmod` and it will work.

Comment: And it seems we got [a new CRAN version overnight](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/index.html). If you use binaries you have to wait until they are built, if you build from source 0.4.25 is there for you now.